# error says " java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to" when I'm not even casting ArrayList to the class

Tags: hibernate, servlets, arraylist, download, classcastexception

There is probably something I'm missing here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

So I wrote a Servlet that is, essentially, designed to help me download a file from a database, or a Book, if you will. Now I know that this error:

> 22:05:18,349 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /PubHub/DownloadBook: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to examples.pubhub.model.Book
>       at examples.pubhub.servlets.DownloadBookServlet.doGet(DownloadBookServlet.java:37)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

means that I'm unsafely casting ArrayList to an object of which ArrayList isn't a subclass of. The problem is, I'm not even casting ArrayList to that object, in this case, Book.

I'm not sure what is causing the problem, and I have checked the Entity, and even searched through other places for the same casting:

Servlet code:

```
package examples.pubhub.servlets;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import examples.pubhub.dao.BookDAO;
import examples.pubhub.model.Book;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DownloadBookservlet
 */
@WebServlet("/DownloadBook")
public class DownloadBookServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    /* String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn_13"); */

    String isbn = request.getParameter("isbn_13");

    BookDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getBookDAO();
    Book book = dao.getBookByISBN(isbn);

    // In order to download the PDF to the client, we need to add a data stream to the response.
    // First we set the content type to PDF, so the browser knows how to interpret the data it's receiving
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    // Then we set the filename to the book's title, so it's not a random string of characters
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + book.getTitle() + ".pdf");

    // Create the input stream (IN to the app FROM the book)
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(book.getContent());

    // Create the output stream (OUT of the app TO the client)
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    // We're going to read and write 1KB at a time
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    // Reading returns -1 when there's no more data left to read.
    while (is.read(buffer) != -1) {
        os.write(buffer);
        }


    // Always close your streams!
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
    }
}
```

Code for the method that is causing the error:

```
@Override
public Book getBookByISBN(String isbn) {

    Session session = DAOUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    session.beginTransaction();

    Query query = session.createQuery("from Book where isbn_13 =:isbn_13");
    query.setParameter("isbn_13", isbn);

    Book book = (Book) query.uniqueResult();

    session.getTransaction().commit();

    return book;

}
```

Code for the actual class/object/entity, Book:

```
package examples.pubhub.model;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

@Id
@Column(name="isbn_13")
public String isbn_13;  // International Standard Book Number, unique

@Column(name="title")
private String title;

@Column(name="author")
private String author;

@Column(name="publish_date")
private LocalDate publish_date; // Date of publish to the website

@Column(name="price")
private double price;

@Column(name="content")
private byte[] content;

// Constructor used when no date is specified
public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, byte[] content, double price) {
    super();
    this.isbn_13 = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publish_date = LocalDate.now();
    this.content = content;
    this.price = price;
}

// Constructor used when a date is specified
public Book(String isbn, String title, String author, LocalDate publishDate, double price, byte[] content) {
    super();
    this.isbn_13 = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.publish_date = publishDate;
    this.content = content;
    this.price = price;
}

// Default constructor
public Book() {

}

public String getIsbn_13() {
    return isbn_13;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public LocalDate getPublish_date() {
    return publish_date;
}


public void setPublish_date(LocalDate publishDate) {
    this.publish_date = publishDate;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public byte[] getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(byte[] content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public void setIsbn_13(String isbn) {
    this.isbn_13 = isbn;

}
```

As you can see, I'm not casting Array List (I spelled it this way to get through spellcheck) to it. But maybe there is something I'm not getting when trying to cast it to this entity. The hibernate version I'm using is 5.1.6 (5.2 has its issues).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something is off already in that line 37 in DownloadBookServlet is not an executable line in the code you posted.  At a guess, getBookByISBN() returns a List<Book> but the code you show isn't what is really being executed.  Recheck your build environment - you're not using the classes you think you are.

Comment: Well, it returns a record containing all the properties from book. Is that technically considered a List? Shouldn't it be an Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. The problem was in how I mapped other classes using Hibernate.